# Qt application does not respond to mouse and keyboard events

Tags: c++, qt, events, static

I recently upgraded my application from using a dynamic build of QT to a static. However, ever since the upgrade I am not able to:

- Trigger mouse events: I am not able to click any widget, there is simply no animation (window is static).
- Trigger keyboard events: I can not enter a value in the default focused QSpinBox.

Some remarks:

- When the upgrade was performed, no style was set for the application (however in the dynamic build, there was a style). I fixed this by using application.setStyle("fusion")
- I see the cursor of the QSpinBox blinking. In my experience this indicates that the GUI-thread is not "stuck" somewhere.

Comment: "Upgraded" how, exactly?

Comment: Changed is maybe a better word. Instead of using dll's, I now have a static build of QT .lib's that I refer to.

Comment: This seems you're missing functionality from what is otherwise loaded from plugins, such as style and input plugins. Which platform is this?

Comment: I use Windows, however; I do use "Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin);"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the GUI thread was not the main thread (this is also being logged)